# Dax Related function returns all zero column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables which are related in a one-to-many fashion.

[image: Data model]

When I use related with string value columns as store name or even integer value columns it works fine and brings the correct value. 
However when I try to bring the column I am interested in ("number of clients"), which is a numeric column, it only brings a column with 0 values.

I transform the column to string and even in that case it returns all 0 string value. Even if I concatenate the column with another string column like "store name", it will return the correct store name but with the number of clients transformed to zero.

I have compared the properties of the other numeric columns that work well with related and they seem to have the same settings. I have seen posts about people having trouble with related functions so I made a new report and imported the 2 tables again but the same thing happens.

Also when trying with lookupvalue I face the same issue.
please help!

Edit: here is an example of the situation with data

[image: example]

So in the background I have the table of the many side of the relation. I have added 2 columns, one in which the related function works, by bringing the client type data and the other one that doesn't work which should bring the number of clients data. ** the numbers of client type don't match in the shown tables because of the one to many relation.

In the front I placed a sample of the number of clients table where the client type and the number of clients are shown. 
So both of the columns from client number table are numerical but somehow one column gets related correctly and the other one gets transformed to only zero values.

Comment: Can you show some example data and what DAX you've tried?

Comment: hey @AlexisOlson, I just added some example but I have so much data and I am not allowed to share it. Is it possible to upload pbix files here? Let me know if you get any ideas of what might be going wrong with what I uploaded, if not I will try to recreate the problem with dummy data. Thanks

Comment: You never need to share confidential information; just something representative to demonstrate your issue. Best practice is to create dummy data that's [minimal, complete, and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can't host PBIX files on SO directly but it's common to link to files on Google Drive or Dropbox for that kind of thing.